# Role of off-chain workers

Tags: substrate

I'm trying to build a mental model of the role of off-chain workers in substrate. The bigger picture seems to be that they move logic inside the substrate node, that was otherwise done by oracles, triggering on predefined transactions. There are two use cases I was thinking of specifically:

1: Validating file formats: incoming transaction proposes a file accessible via url or ipfs hash, and it's format needs to be validated. An off-chain worker fetches the file, asserts format (size, encoding, content, whatever) and if correct submits another transaction saying it's valid.

2: Key generation: let's assume there is a separate service distributed with the substrate node, which manages keys for each instance. Node A runs a key sharing algorithm (like Shamir's secret sharing) via this external service between participants A, B and C, then makes a transaction creating a group (A,B,C) on-chain. This transaction triggers all nodes that are in this group to run off-chain workers, call into their local key store verifying having the key. They can all mark it on-chain afterwards.

As far as I understand it correctly, off-chain workers are triggered in every node after block execution. In the former use case, this would result in lots of transactions validating just one file, and nothing guarantees the correctness of these. What is a good way of reaching consensus on the validity of the file? Is it also possible without economic incentives like staking? It would be problematic with tokens having no value in the network, e.g in enterprise settings. Is this even the right use case for off-chain workers? The second example should not suffer from such issue, we just need all parties to verify having the key.

Where does the thought process above go wrong, and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As far as I understand it correctly, off-chain workers are triggered in every node after block execution.

Yes and no. There is a CLI flag for it. And at the time of this writing it says:

```
        --offchain-worker <ENABLED>
            Should execute offchain workers on every block.

            By default it's only enabled for nodes that are authoring new blocks. [default: WhenValidating]  [possible
            values: Always, Never, WhenValidating]
```

> In the former use case, this would result in lots of transactions validating just one file, and nothing guarantees the correctness of these.

I think it is the responsibility of the receiving function (aka. `Call`) to handle and incentivise this. For example, there could be a reward opportunity to validate an address. But, if it has already been submitted by another transaction, you will get slashed (or even if not, you do pay some transaction fee, for nothing). In such cases, you can assume that not all participants will submit a transaction. They will only do it when there is a chance of improvement, which should be depicted by your potential reward/slash scheme.

> Is this even the right use case for off-chain workers?

I am no expert here, but I think at least the validation example is a good example. It is just a matter of finding a good incentive + anti-spam slashing.

I am less familiar with the second example, so no comments on that.