# Offchain Workers & Signed Transactions

Tags: blockchain, substrate

It's stated that `fn offchain_worker` function is called every time by all nodes after a block import. Imagine the case where in `fn offchain_worker` we make a http call to fetch some not deterministic value from a remote server, and once we get the result we call to `pub fn onchain_callback` to sign a transaction to include that result in the blockchain state.

If Off-chain workers are executed by all validators after each block import, would I end up with one new signed transaction per validator with different results (remember is not deterministic).

Example. My Off-chain worker fetch a random number from a remote server and callback the result signing a new transaction. If I have in my network 10 validators... questions:

1.- I would end up with 10 new transactions with different random numbers?

2.- It would be executed only by the validators or also by all the full nodes connected to the blockchain?

3.- Is it possible to trigger the Off-chain workers only when a certain extrinsic is included in the block, instead of after every block import?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes, if the validators run with default off-chain workers settings.
   If this is not desired, your OCW can pick a validator or introduce a
   random delay & extra conditions between different runs. We do that
   for im-online pallet in substrate repo or offchain phragmen
   elections.
2. Other nodes can opt-in with a CLI flag (and most likely extra keys
   to sign transactions), but you can also put a guard in your OCW code
   to run only in case sp_io::offchain::is_validator() == true
3. That has to be done manually for now - off-chain worker has full
   state access so it can inspect the Events in frame_system and only
   run in case some specific one is there. I believe there are some
   examples in substrate-recipies repo fo that.

More information here: [Role of off-chain workers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59401972/role-of-off-chain-workers)